# XML version-specific deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

So, I have a base project and several modified version of it. *BaseProject* contains class *BaseClass*,

```
namespace BaseProject.SomeClasses{
    public abstract class BaseClass{
    //...
    }
}
```

while each of the versions contain several inheritors of *BaseClass* - f.e. *ProjectOne*:

```
namespace BaseProject.VersionOne.SomeClasses{
    public class InheritorClass : BaseClass{
    //Some logic here...
    }
}
```

and *ProjectTwo*:

```
namespace BaseProject.VersionTwo.SomeClasses{
    public class InheritorClass : BaseClass{
    //Some different logic here...
    }
}
```

The only thing that differs is the name of the namespace.

Base project loads each of the assemblies during the runtime and gets all of the inherited types. I need to create the xml file, which should contain both of the inheritors' instances and some pointers to the class which the instance should be deserialized into:

```
...
<BaseClass xsi:type="InheritorClass"> <!-- From VersionOne -->
    <PropOne></PropOne>
    <PropTwo></PropTwo>
    <PropThree></PropThree>
    <!-- ... -->
</BaseClass>
<BaseClass xsi:type="InheritorClass"> <!-- From VersionTwo -->
    <PropFour></PropFour>
    <PropFive></PropFive>
    <PropSix></PropSix>
    <!-- ... -->
</BaseClass>
...
```

Is there any way to deserialize this xml (which contains the instances of inheritors from both of the versions) into `IEnumerable<BaseClass>`?

Comment: You need to qualify your elements with a given namespace

Comment: @MartinCh, ok, but how do I link xml namespace and C# namespace if I can access the latter only during the runtime?

Comment: I am not getting the logic of what you want to achieve - Base class is a parent - your inheritorclasses - are inherited - specializations - you can not cast a child back to the parent without loosing staff that was added into childs

Comment: @MartinCh, each of the inheritor classes has the same methods as the parent, so I can just override them and use with inheritor-specific parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the [`[XmlTypeAttribute(name)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to your derived classes to disambiguate the `xst:type` names:

```
namespace BaseProject.VersionOne.SomeClasses
{
    [XmlType("VersionOneInheritorClass")]
    public class InheritorClass : BaseClass
    {
        public string VersionOneProperty { get; set; } // For instance
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace BaseProject.VersionTwo.SomeClasses
{
    [XmlType("VersionTwoInheritorClass")]
    public class InheritorClass : BaseClass
    {
        public string VersionTwoProperty { get; set; } // For instance
    }
}
```

Then your XML will appear as follows, and can be serialized and deserialized successfully without loss of information:

> ```
> <BaseClass xsi:type="VersionOneInheritorClass">
>     <VersionOneProperty>one</VersionOneProperty>
> </BaseClass>
> <BaseClass xsi:type="VersionTwoInheritorClass">
>     <VersionTwoProperty>two</VersionTwoProperty>
> </BaseClass>
> ```

By the way, if you are constructing an `XmlSerializer` using the [`XmlSerializer (Type, Type[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor to add in your discovered derived types, you must [cache the serializer in a static cache somewhere](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or else you will have a horrible resource leak.

Comment: Well, I also customized Serializer a little and this worked perfect!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The namespace of the class shouldn't make a difference.  See XML file generate by this code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Root root = new Root()
            {
                baseClass = new List<BaseClass>(){
                    new InheritorClass1(){ name = "class1"},
                    new InheritorClass2(){ name = "class2"}
                }
            };
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, root);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            Root newRoot = (Root)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement("BaseClass")]
        public List<BaseClass> baseClass { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("BaseClass")]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(InheritorClass1))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(InheritorClass2))]
    public class BaseClass
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }    

    }
    [XmlRoot("InheritorClass1")]
    public class InheritorClass1 : BaseClass
    {
    }

    [XmlRoot("InheritorClass2")]
    public class InheritorClass2 : BaseClass
    {
    }

}
​
```